# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am getting this error : {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."} I have tried with setting the `ServicePointManage.SecurityProtocol` to different values and what I noticed is that some times I get respond from the server and sometimes not. Also, but I am not sure why changes the security protocol each time I get the error helps the next time I run the application to get respond so I am not sure if the issue is from the way I set the security protocol or from the server it self also I have tried accessing the link from the browser and everything works fine please view my code and suggest me with suggestions all answers related to this post are not helpful.

```
private string getLocationIDfromGlassDoor(string location)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation))
{
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20000000;
string url = "www.xxx.com";
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Proxy = null;
request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Host = "www.xxx.co.uk";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0";
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
try
{
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
// Do your processings here....
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = null;
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
else
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
//string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
var data = ReadFully(receiveStream, 32000);
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
doc.LoadHtml(result);
JObject json = JObject.Parse(result);
var locationId = (string)json.Descendants().OfType
<JProperty>
().First(a => a.Name == "id");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationId))
{
readStream.Close();
receiveStream.Close();
return locationId;
}
else
{
errors.Add("Error");
return "";
}
}
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
errors.Add(e.Message);
}
}
return "";
}
```

Also I have tried setting the keepAlive to false. and also I have tried the following:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

I am not sure what else I am missing so that I get a respond each time I make request as expected.

Comment: request.Method = "POST"; or as per your method type

Comment: Sorry but that did not work I am still getting the same error

Comment: Is there any port used ?

Comment: no just accessing a normal site

Comment: if you call from a secured side api ,then you should use as like ,can display api code